# AMQP error while attempting pushRaw: The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting incoming data

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, connection-timeout, socket-timeout-exception, php-amqplib

- Laravel version: 6.0
- RabbitMQ version: 3.6.15
- RabbitMQ Package: https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/tree/v9.1.2

In our application we have to dispatch tens of thousands messages daily and most of them are dispatched without any problem but some are not dispatched in the queue, the quantity is in hundreds. This is the error I could find out:
`production.ERROR: AMQP error while attempting pushRaw: The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting incoming data`
The messages which are not dispatched are lost.

I tried to increase the read_write_timeout but there is no direct way to increase the timeout using config apparently in this version of package. I verified my connection settings and everything is fine.
What could be done to resolve this error?